# SQL Server 2017 Installation Fails on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

I am attempting to install SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition on Windows 10 but I am getting an error "Exception has been throw by the target of the invocation."  That is less than helpful.

[image]

If I run the System Configuration Checker, the setup administrator rule fails.  I am at a loss to explain the failure since this I have one account on my computer and I am in the Administrator group.  This computer is not part of a Windows domain.  I tried running setup as an administrator by right-clicking run as administrator and got the same results.

Unsure if this is causing the setup failure but I figured it is where I should start.  It is not even starting the setup so I don't think a log file is created that I can look at.  I tried running the setup as administrator and I get the same results.  Ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Found out the setup log file is located in the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log.  So I checked the error log and the error message was

Unable to load DLL 'sqlmu.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Sure enough that file was missing.  So I re-downloaded the ISO and extracted it and now setup runs fine.  Must have been a corrupted download.  Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Try running the setup file as Administrator (Right Click -> Run as Administrator).

Comment: Tried that and same results.  I thought I had included that in my question but had not.  I edited the question so it is in there now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SQL Server installation fails if the Setup account doesn't have certain user rights](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2000257/sql-server-installation-fails-if-the-setup-account-doesn-t-have-certai) article, and following the steps included. Does that work?

Comment: Nope.  I ran the Local Security Policy and gave my account rights to Backup files and directories, Debug Programs, and Manage auditing and security log as described in the article.  I tried running the accesschk tool to verify my rights but I'm getting...Error enumerating account rights for <user account>:
A specified privilege does not exist.
No matching objects found.